# Update child entities from parent entity

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

According to the scenario below, I would like to update child entities from parent entity.

I approached the problem as follows.

1. Child entities of parent delete from database.
2. New child entities of parent add from database.

Is that approach true way ?

```
    public int SaveBasket(Addition addition)
    {
        var entity = ApplicationDbContext.Additions.Include(x => x.Basket).SingleOrDefault(x => x.AdditionId == addition.AdditionId);

        //Remove Basket
        if (entity.Basket.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in entity.Basket)
            {
                context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }

            ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Add new basket entities from posting json data
        entity.Basket = addition.Basket;

        return ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the following:

```
    public int SaveBasket(Addition addition)
    {
        var entity = ApplicationDbContext.Additions.Find(addition.AdditionId); // Find by primary key

        //Remove Basket
        if (entity.Basket.Count > 0)
        {
            entity.Basket.Clear(); // Empty out the basket

            ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Add new basket entities from posting json data
        addition.Basket.ForEach(b => entity.Basket.Add(b)); // Add the items

        return ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Hard to tell what your data structure is, but this should help.

**Update**

From your comment, it sounds like you want to remove the entire `basket` record.

```
    public int SaveBasket(Addition addition)
    {
        var baskets = ApplicationDbContext.Basket.Where(b => b.AdditionId == addition.AdditionId);

        //Remove Basket
        ApplicationDbContext.Basket.RemoveRange(baskets);
        ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        ApplicationDbContext.Basket.AddRange(addition.Basket);
        return ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Basket comes null

Comment: I included basket entity and then i tried debug, entity.Basket.Clear(); just remove column value on Basket entityt so does not delete completely.

Comment: So you have to delete the basket entity?

Comment: yes i have to delete it, i have order screen, i called it basket. I can add and delete products from the basket. I have to empty the basket every time I add or delete it because it gives the same ID error. For example, I've added 2 of the same products to the basket, then re-entering the basket, reducing or adding the product quantity, and sending it to update the information. I empty the basket first and then add the incoming data if I do not do so, I get the same identity error.

Comment: Then you may want to consider doing a comparison and updating instead of wiping it all out then adding it again. Possibly by item ID and count.

Comment: I think it's better to delete them all.
Because, it will take longer to make comparisons and there may be a decrease in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your models look like, you might be able to just do this for deleting and adding children.

```
public int SaveBasket(Addition addition)
{
    var dbAddition = ApplicationDbContext.Additions
        .Include(x => x.Basket)
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.AdditionId == addition.AdditionId);

    ApplicationDbContext.Basket.RemoveRange(dbAddition.Basket);
    ApplicationDbContext.Basket.AddRange(addition.Basket);

    return ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: removerange not a function to dbAddition

Comment: You're right, I was a bit too fast.  RemoveRange and AddRange should have been called on ApplicationDbContext.Basket.